# Disaggregate count by column content after group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I've got the following table in SQL Server:

| ExperienceId | EmployeeId | ExperienceType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'Work' |
| 2 | 1 | 'Internal' |
| 3 | 2 | 'Internal' |
| 4 | 3 | 'External' |
| 5 | 3 | 'External' |

There are only 3 possible values of `ExperienceType`: 'Work', 'Internal' and 'External'

I'd like to know how many experiences of each type has each employee:

| EmployeeId | Work exp | Internal exp | External exp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

I've tried this

```sql
select EmployeeId, count(*)
from EmployeeExperiences
group by EmployeeId
```

But that only gives me the total number of experiences per employee, and I don't know how to disaggregate that by ExperienceType.

Comment: A place to start is to search for PIVOT. I think that's what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use conditional aggregation (`CASE WHEN` inside the aggregation function).

```
select 
  employeeid,
  count(case when experiencetype = 'Work' then 1 end) as work_exp,
  count(case when experiencetype = 'Internal' then 1 end) as internal_exp,
  count(case when experiencetype = 'External' then 1 end) as external_exp
from employeeexperiences
group by employeeid
order by employeeid;
```

Another option is to use the `PIVOT` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Result with PIVOT:

```
select EmployeeId, [Work], [Internal], [External] from (
  select EmployeeId, ExperienceType from EmployeeExperiences) as SourceTable
  pivot (
    count(ExperienceType ) for ExperienceType in ([Work], [Internal], [External])) as 
  PivotTable
```